# Explore structure packaging

Tags: c, memory, struct, bit, bit-fields

I want to understand how the structure is stored on a little endian machine and in case of packed variables.

Let's assume I have the below structure with bitfields:

```
struct my_struct {
    short a;
    short b: 6;
    short c: 10;
    int d;
    int e: 28;
    int f: 4;
}
```

Can someone explain me how this structure is being layouted in the memory.

Comment: The exact representation of bit fields is implementation-defined. Some compilers pack them starting from least-significant bits, others from most-significant; there probably exist those that do something else still. The same program may very well behave differently when compiled with different compilers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I have the question in the first and the last time. I want to know how the above structure is layed out in the memory

Comment: You can read about bitfields for c [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field) and c++ [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).

Comment: It would be a fruitful exercise for you to explore that for yourself. You will have to do this kind of thing many, many times in the future so make a start right now.

Comment: To make this question answerable, please choose a particular CPU architecture.

Comment: @wallyk incase of intel x86

Comment: @WeatherVane I found it by traversing through each bite, i want someone to answer so i can assume my findings are correct

Comment: @IgorTandetnik incase of intel x86 and gcc

Comment: I suggest you first place a `1` value in each `struct` member and explore a dump. There is not enough code posted to make it easy for us.

Comment: `0xIJ` what is that?

Comment: @user04556 does 0xGHIJ represents hexadecimal values?

Comment: Where do you get 12 bytes? Looks like 14 to me...2 for A, 1 for B, 2 for C, 4 for D & E, 1 for F. Some compilers might combine B & C into a word, so that would be 13.

Comment: @krpra yes they are hex values

Comment: @user04556 Which operating system?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker size is 12 because of packing, sizeof struct prints 12

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker yes the fictitious data does not fit the fields available, which when packed is 12 bytes.

Comment: @WeatherVane, you don't use base 18 when you write in C?

Comment: Ah, E & F might be combined as well.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker i was agreeing with you. The definition seems to take 12 bytes but the data is romantic.

Comment: @fuz any linux distribution but 32bit

Comment: Which ABI? Which target platform? Which implementation? How wide is `short`? How wide `int`? What about padding? Alignment? … C or C++? Different languages.

Comment: @WeatherVane 379 in base 20 :P

Comment: @Olaf 'Let's assume my word size is 32bit(32bit machine), int is 32bit and short is 16bit'  There is no padding, it's a packed structure

Comment: I suggest you remove either the "c" or "c++" tag, depending on which language you're actually using. You should also remove the "assembly" tag, since your question isn't about assembly language.

Comment: @KeineLust sorry my calculator only goes [up to eleven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven). can you recommend an up to 42 radix calculator?

Comment: If you are interested in the behavior of a particular implementation on a particular machine, then just test it with that implementation on that machine, and see for yourself.

Comment: @user04556 Did you read the ABI documentation for your platform? You can find it [here](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf), it should clear up your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set each member to the `1` and explore bit representation of structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct my_struct {
    short a;
    short b : 6;
    short c : 10;
    int d;
    int e : 28;
    int f : 4;
};

int main(void) {
    struct my_struct my_struct;

    my_struct.a = 0x1;
    my_struct.b = 0x1;
    my_struct.c = 0x1;
    my_struct.d = 0x1;
    my_struct.e = 0x1;
    my_struct.f = 0x1;

    int size = sizeof(my_struct);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        unsigned char byte = *((unsigned char *)&my_struct + i);
        for (int i = CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            printf((byte >> i) & 0x1 ? "1" : "0");
        }
        printf(" ");
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this matches with my program and findings